# Metric Space and Uniformly Continuous Functions

Tags: real-analysis

Find an unbounded set $A$ such that every function from $A$ to a metric space is uniformly
continuous.

I'm drawing a blank for this problem. I've been just looking over the definitions on wiki, and am not really sure how to proceed here.

Answer (score 3):

We will begin by analysing some particular types of functions that must be (uniformly) continuous to help determine properties of such a set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

- First, note that for each $x_0 \in A$ the function $f_{x_0} : A \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f_{x_0} ( x ) = \begin{cases}1,&\text{if }x = x_0\\0,&\text{if }x \neq x_0\end{cases}$$ must be *continuous* (forgetting the *uniformly* part for the moment). Then $f_{x_0}^{-1} [ (\frac{1}{2} , \frac{3}{2} ) ] = \{ x_0 \}$ must be an open subset of $A$, which tells us that $x_0$ is an *isolated point* of $A$.

  So every point of $A$ must be isolated, meaning that $A$ is a discrete subspace of $\mathbb{R}$.
- Now suppose that $A$ has an accumulation point $y$ (which by the above cannot belong to $A$). Then there must be a one-to-one sequence $\langle x_n \rangle_{n=0}^\infty$ in $A$ which converges to $y$.  Note that the function $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
  0, &\text{if }x = x_{2n}\text{ for some }n\\
  1, &\text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}$$ is uniformly continuous. So there is an $\delta > 0$ such that $| f(x) - f(x^\prime) | < \frac{1}{2}$ whenever $|x-x^\prime| < \delta$. Since the sequence $\langle x_n \rangle_{n=0}^\infty$ is Cauchy, there is an $N$ such that $| x_n - x_m | < \delta$ for all $n,m > 0$, and in particular $| x_N - x_{N+1} | < \delta$. But note that $| f(x_N) - f(x_{N+1}) | = 1$

  Therefore $A$ has no accumulation points, and in particular $A$ is closed.

It shouldn't be too difficult to show that a familiar unbounded, closed, discrete subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (*e.g.*, $\mathbb{Z}$) actually works.

Comment: can you please explain the first part of your answer? What is the inference of "very important about the points of A"?

Comment: @Martin: I have considerably expanded my answer. Everything should be pretty clear now.

Comment: @ArthurFischer My question is in regard to the first bullet of your answer. To help elucidate my confusion, suppose $A=(0,2)$. Now for $x_0 \in A$ , the function $f_{x_0}(x)$ is continuous and $f_{x_0}^{-1} [ (\frac{1}{2} , \frac{3}{2} ) ] = \{ x_0 \}$. From there you draw that every point of $A$ is isolated. How can this be? I understand how you draw that $\{x_0\}$ is open, but the open sets of $A$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ are just $\{A\cap B| B~open~in~\mathbb{R}\}$, right?

Comment: @user151852: If $A = (0,2)$, then the function $f_{1}$, for example, is _not_ (uniformly) continuous. This then implies that _this set_ $(0,2)$ cannot be an example of set satisfying the criteria of the question. (And, yes, the open subsets of $A$ are of the form $A \cap B$ where $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is open. There _are_ subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ where every point is isolated: _e.g._, $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\{ \frac{1}{n} : n \geq 1 \}$. But not even all of _these_ will work.)