# Finding an unbounded set with a specific property

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, continuity, uniform-continuity

Find an unbounded subset $A ⊂ \Bbb R$ such that every function from $A$ to a metric space is uniformly continuous.

My attempt at the solution (incomplete).

If $A⊆ \Bbb R$ were such a set, then for each $x_{0} ∈A$ the function $f_{x_{0}}:A→\Bbb R$ defined by
$f_{x_{0}}(x)=\{1$,if $x=x_{0}$

```
        $0,if $ x≠x_{0} $
```

is continuous.

I don't know how to proceed further. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

1. Suppose A has discrete metric, then every function frome it to a metric space is uniformly continuous.
2. Now you are asked to find a set $A\subset \mathbb{R}$, such that every function from to metric space $Y$ it is uniformly continuous **in terms of the subspace topology** (This is what $f:A\to Y$ is uniformly continuous means). Note the induced subspace topology on a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ can have discrete metric even if $\mathbb{R}$ has standard metric. Now can you find an unbounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ whose subspace topology is discrete metric?

   > $\mathbb{N}\subset \mathbb{R}$ has discrete metric.

Comment: No I am not thinking to use it. My question is more general for the usual metric on $\Bbb R$

Comment: @Martin So what's your topology on R?

Comment: Usual distance metric $|x-y|$

Comment: @Martin OK. Then which part of my answer do you have question?

Comment: I just don't want to use discrete metric space, can it be done without this assumption?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit on your 2nd part as well? I do not understand it.

Comment: @Martin I have added more details.

Comment: Please give a definition of "the induced subspace topology". Also since I have not read about this (I am doing first course in analysis), can you please explain "the induced subspace topology on a subset of R can have discrete metric even if R has standard metric"-How?

Comment: @Martin Here is a definition for [metric subspace](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Metric_Subspace). And to show a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ can have discrete metric, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514459/prove-that-n-with-its-usual-metric-inherited-from-r-is-a-discrete-metric-space).

Comment: Hi, I have not been taught about metric subspace yet. So, I think I cannot use that now,
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356962/metric-space-and-uniformly-continuous-functions I found this link but I do not seem to understand this. Can you help me with this proof?